# Is the empty set a neighborhood of itself?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

My topology textbook (Lee, Introduction to Manifolds) says

> a $\textbf{neighborhood}$ of $p$ is just an open
>   subset of $X$ containing $p$. More generally, if $K\subseteq X$, a neighborhood of the subset $K$ is an open subset containing $K$. (In some books, the word “neighborhood” is used in the more general sense of a subset containing an open subset containing $p$ or $K$; but for us neighborhoods are always open subsets.)

The empty set is an open subset of every topology, by definition. The empty set also "contains" itself, in the sense that $\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset$. Since it meets these two conditions, is it not a neighborhood of itself?

The answer to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403493/the-empty-set-is-a-neighborhood) states

> The empty set ∅ is not a neighborhood of any point $x∈X$, because as you correctly observed, there are no elements of ∅.

However, nowhere in this definition are sets with no elements explicitly excluded from consideration for being neighborhoods.

Comment: $\in$ and $\subseteq$ are not the same; thus (in mathematics) there are **not** two "senses" of *contains*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Am I correct in saying that $\subseteq$ is the one that mathematicians use?

Comment: As often in math (alas !) terminologi is not so standard as expercted; see [Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)#Notation_and_terminology) : The expressions "A includes x" and "A contains x" are also used to mean set membership, however some authors use them to mean instead "x is a subset of A".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, and it matches with the idea that $\varnothing$ is a neighborhood of each of its elements (although there are no points it is a neighborhood of), because there aren't any elements not to be a neighborhood of.  Every set is a neighborhood of the empty set in the sense defined there.